# Office365 API Authentication - Azure vs Application Registration Portal

Tags: azure, oauth, office365

I'm creating a Node app that uses OAuth2 to login a user and use the Office365 API to send and receive email, and possibly contacts and calendar events.

I have no need for Azure Active Directory that I know of. However, I am unsure of whether or not I need to register the app with Azure for the OAuth flow.

At first I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/node), which involves registering the app in the "Application Registration Portal." The OAuth token I receive *currently* works with the REST API for Outlook. No Azure.

Then I saw [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/getting-started-Office-365-APIs?javascript), which seems to suggest that any app using the Office365 APIs should register an app with Azure. I don't want to do this if I don't have to, mainly because of the cost.

It is not clear to me why I need to sign up for one or the other, and my main concern is that the first tutorial is dated to the point that my app's registration with the "Application Registration Portal" will become deprecated and I will need to switch over to registration with Azure at some point. I have seen plenty of outdated tutorials and information from MS that are not clearly marked as deprecated. Can anyone help clear this up?

Comment: I had the exact same question. The documentation on the topic is terrible. Just show one or the other. Or explain why one would be used over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion. The short answer is that both these methods are still relevant, so none of them are deprecated yet.

Firstly, you're right that you need to register your app to call the Office 365 APIs.

And, you're also right that there are currently two different places to register an app: the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) and [the Active Directory section under the Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

Registering on either one of these is enough to get you to a comfortable state where you can call the Office 365 APIs.

However, the convergence of the Outlook.com stack with the Exchange stack means that you are now also able to use the Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contacts API against consumer Outlook.com accounts in addition to Office 365 accounts. If you wish to take advantage of this, you should register your app in the Application Registration Portal and NOT the Azure Management Portal.

Another advantage of registering through the Application Registration Portal is the support of dynamic permissions scopes. You don't have to specify upfront when you register your app what permissions it requires; rather, you can request permissions at runtime using the scopes parameter.

This new v2 app model for apps registered in the Application Registration Portal is currently in preview. A reason not to register apps in the Application Registration Portal is if they will be using more than just the Mail, Calendar and Contacts APIs. e.g. if your app is also using the OneDrive for Business Files API, you wouldn't be able to request tokens using the v2 app model's endpoint. In that case, you should register your app in the Active Directory section under the Azure Management Portal.